# Blogger api always return 401 error response

Tags: android, api, http, android-volley, blogger

I use `Volley` to send HTTP requests in my android app. I looked for a number of answers on the internet but couldn't find anything.

---

I use Blogger API and send `HTTP` request for getting my blogs using the get blogs by URL method as given in the documentation

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs
>   Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */

I added the Authorization header correctly in the `getHeaders()` method correctly as stated in the documentation:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Authorization", "My_Auth_Key");
    return params;
}
```

also I did the set up process in the google API console correctly as you can see. I added my package name, i.e., `gq.gouravkhunger.blogger` and the app's `SHA Fingerprint` correctly:
[image: Google API console image]

But when I test the app, I always get this error:

[image: Android Debugging Volley 401 error]

Comment: error 401 means you are not authorized to access the resource, there must be some issues with credentials...check them(https://httpstatuses.com/401)

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: (Note that if the API key in this question was the real one, then note it is still in the revision history. I suggest you invalidate that with your API provider.)

Comment: I did it. Anyways thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your OAUTH key is valid?
And also make sure you are not using APIKey where you are supposed to use OAUTH.
Read the documentation to understand better

You can get OAUTH Key from [OAUTH Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) for testing

Comment: hey @JideGuru, can you tell me how this OAuth key looks like? Or suggest me what is it: API Key or OAuth Client ID?

Comment: also whats the Client Secret? I didn't get any client secret!

Comment: **OAUTH** is used when your app requires the user to login.
**APIKey** on the other hand is used when you don't need private data.

Comment: I want to use OAuth but what i should put the value in the Authorization `HTTP Header`? I don't know this. When i debug the app, Android studio says that unexpected response code 401 is sent by the website

Comment: If you are requesting with a URL it should look something like this.
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs?access_token=your_token

Your authorization header should be a **valid** OAUTH access token.
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs
Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */`

Make sure your token is **valid** because you will get error 401 if it is **invalid**

Comment: OAuth token looks like this.
`ya29.GlsYBr97uWgvTVfGwSpoCM4lWQ63C7vdVcH8O-tCV2hYQ7bpYNRbPlENhVlAavvFu4E6A20BoaJkYclmCiyVrLPWvw0mLuisAoQM0lNneqrJOQrYomyDN_FlBz0X`

and it expires with time. the one above is expired already.
You can generate one from the OAuth Playground